# How to check if is null in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, native

I'm trying to validate data from firebase.

try {

```
 const id = this.context.getCurrentUser( { } ).uid  //get user's id

 const user = await this.context.validPlantao(id) // check if got data from firebase.
```

above 'const user' it' s working, If got some data, return these infos, but if is empty returns null.

i've gotta verify this code below

```
            if(user == null){
                console.log('can register data') 
                                
            }else{
                console.log('you even are registered') 
            }
```

That If condition isn't working.
When have nothing in firebase 'const user' returns null. What i want to do is check, if have no register, they can save. But, if have an register, show an alert mensager

Comment: I prefer installing Lodash and check with isNull or isEmpty. There are other simple methods you can use through development

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
        if(user){
            console.log('can register data') 
                            
        }else{
            console.log('you even are registered') 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
If (!user) {
DO stuff
} else {
Do something else
}
```

If that dus not work try logging posible solutions u til you Get it to give true if null.
Like:

```
console.log(user === false);
console.log(user === null) ;
```

If a value is null it should also give true if you do the check with false

Answer (score 0):

You may check

```
if(variable){Do Something} else {Do Something}
```

Or if u want to check a key in an object and using babel you may use chaning like

```
if(obj?.key){Do Something} else {Do Something}
```

also if you are interested in returning something simple you may use shorthand check

```
return variable ? "Do something if True" : "Do something if False"
```